# Definición y uso de una Class en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Despues de la IO que todo va enfocado a Kotlin, me he decidido en hacer el salto...

Pero ya no ser como avanzar, como se define una class en Kotlin, por lo leido no es necesario especificar los getters ni setters, pero como se pueden rescribir para que antes de agregar el valor se evalué.

```
class Person {
   private var name : String? = null;
   private var age : Int;
   private val adult : Boolean;
}
```

¿Quiero que cuando se especifique una edad pues compruebe que si es adulto o no `>18` y como se accede a sus valores con un objeto creado...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas definir valores default esta sería la declaración:

```
class Person () {
    val name : String = "";
    val age : Int = 0
    val adult : Boolean = false
}
```

> Quiero que cuando se especifique una edad pues compruebe que si es
>   adulto o no >18

Este es un ejemplo determinando si la variable `age` es mayor a 18 conserva el valor, de otra forma define como valor para la variable `age` 0 :

```
open class Person (nameI: String, ageI: Int, adultI: Boolean) {
    val name : String;
    val age : Int
    val adult : Boolean

    init { //Inicializa valores
        name = nameI
        age = if (ageI > 18) {
            ageI  //Si es mayor de 18 conserva la edad definida.
        } else {
            0 // Si no es mayor define un valor default, en este caso 0
        }
        adult = adultI

        //Imprime valores
        println("Person name = $name")
        println("Person age = $age")
        println("Person adult = $adult")
    }

}
```

> y como se accede a sus valores con un objeto creado...

Usando como base la clase anterior puedes crear una instancia y acceder a sus propiedades, por ejemplo:

```
   val clasePerson = Person("Webserveis", 21, true)

    Log.d(TAG, "Valor adult : " + clasePerson.adult )
    Log.d(TAG, "Valor age : " + clasePerson.age )
    Log.d(TAG, "Valor name : " + clasePerson.name )
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma; he encontrado como sobrescribir el `setter` en Kotlin

```
class Person() {
    var name: String? = null
    var isAdult : Boolean = false
    var age: Int = 0
        set(age) {
            isAdult = age >= 18
            field = age
        }
}
```

Su uso

```
val People = Person()

People.name = "John"
People.age = 31

println("name: ${People.name}")         //John
println("age: ${People.age}")           //31
println("is adult: ${People.isAdult}")  //true
```